# Laravel 5 Validation - Return as json / ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to post the values into validation and return the response as json rather than `return view` as given in the documentation.

```
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'about' => 'min:1'
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json(['errors' => ?, 'status' => 400], 200);
    }
```

The post is made by ajax so I need to receive the response in the ajax as well.

I figured out that in order to prevent refresh of the page in the returning response, I have to give it a status code of 200 outside the array. But I couldn't figure out what to give the `'errors'` part. What should I write in there?

Comment: `return response()->json(['errors' => $validator->messages(), 'status' => 400], 200);`?

Comment: Small update: REST principles nowadays would require the status code `422` to be used.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can use `$validator->messages()` that returns an array which contains all the information about the validator, including errors. The `json` function takes the array and encodes it as a json string.

```
if ($validator->fails()) {    
    return response()->json($validator->messages(), Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

***Note***: In case of validation errors, It's better not to return response code 200. You can use other status codes like 400 or `Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST`

Comment: You don't have to specify the 200 error_code, since 200 is the default value.

Comment: Mmm. I think we should set status code another than 200, 201. What happen if client-side use `axios` (Javascript API library) to handle by promise :D

Comment: If it failed, you should return a `400`, since it did not succeed. You should also consider using the response code constants, such as `Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST`. A full example would be: `return response()->json($validator->messages(), Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);`

Comment: We should be using FormRequest validation (https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#form-request-validation) rather than inline validation.  See @james-mills solution provided via the link in his response.

Comment: @user3125602 The question is NOT about how to validate a form. It's just about how to return validation errors  in response.

Answer (score 23):

You can also tell Laravel you want a JSON response. Add this header to your request:

```
'Accept: application/json'
```

And Laravel will return a JSON response.

Comment: how can i tell in controller to always return the json, no matter what on server side instead of client side?

Comment: This is the best solution for make working of default logic

Answer (score 10):

In Laravel 5.4 the `validate()` method can automatically detect if your request is an AJAX request, and send the validator response accordingly.

See the documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#form-request-validation)

> If validation fails, a redirect response will be generated to send the user back to their previous location. The errors will also be flashed to the session so they are available for display. If the request was an AJAX request, a HTTP response with a 422 status code will be returned to the user including a JSON representation of the validation errors.

So you could simply do the following:

```
Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'about' => 'min:1'
])->validate();
```

Answer (score 3):

in case you are using a request class.

you may use `failedValidation` to handle you failed

```php
    /**
     * Returns validations errors.
     *
     * @param Validator $validator
     * @throws  HttpResponseException
     */
    protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
    {
        if ($this->wantsJson() || $this->ajax()) {
            throw new HttpResponseException(response()->json($validator->errors(), 422));
        }
        parent::failedValidation($validator);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

For those who have created a custom request class can override the `public function response(array $errors)` method and return a modified response without `Validator` explicitly.

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse;

class CustomRequest extends FormRequest
{

    public function rules()
    {
        $rules = [
            //custom rules    
        ];

        return $rules;
    }

    public function response(array $errors)
    {
        return new JsonResponse(['error' => $errors], 400);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, really that's interesting approach, and if you combine it with `$request->ajax()` you can handle both request types :)

Comment: Exactly,  it is better encapsulated.

Answer (score 2):

I use below this code for API in my existing project.

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [ 
      'ride_id' => 'required',
      'rider_rating' => 'required',
  ]);

  if ($validator->fails()) {
    return response()->json($validator->errors(), 400);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution is to make my own FormRequest class which I put in the root API namespace namespace App\Http\Requests\Api.

Hope this helps someone

https://jamesmills.co.uk/2019/06/05/how-to-return-json-from-laravel-form-request-validation-errors/

Comment: Thank you for your solution - it helped me get validation errors in an API response.  Yes, you're right - FormRequests is the way to go rather than inline validation these days.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I used @Soura solution but with a little change. You need to import the Validator package as well.

```
$validator = \Validator::make($request->all(), [ 
      'ride_id' => 'required',
      'rider_rating' => 'required',
  ]);

  if ($validator->fails()) {
    return response()->json($validator->errors(), 400);
  }
```